# Restart tmux sessions in Ubuntu (running Python)

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, tmux

I have five background processes running in tmux on my Ubuntu server. Each pane is a python script that is a never ending while loop.

```
$ tmux ls
```

```
process1: 1 windows (created Fri Dec 14 10:12:40 2018) [143x31]
process2: 1 windows (created Fri Jan 11 10:23:55 2019) [128x30]
process3: 1 windows (created Sun Feb 10 13:30:03 2019) [143x33]
process4: 1 windows (created Tue Dec 18 22:41:50 2018) [145x33]
process5: 1 windows (created Mon Jan 14 15:42:04 2019) [143x33]
```

Is there a command to stop and start, or restart, all services? Rather than going into each one and manually stopping and restarting it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method will probably involve

```
bind-key * set-window-option synchronize-pane
```

This bind (or any other key you choose to set) will allow you to type `<prefix>*` to begin typing to *all* panes in your window. (Undo this feature with `<prefix>*` again)

For your use case, to stop them all, you'd send `C-C` to all panes by literally typing Ctrl+C. To restart all the processes, just hit the up arrow to go back in each pane's history (or type `!!` if you prefer) and then hit `Enter` to start those up again.

This assumes that starting each process takes the same number of commands in each pane.

I've checked, and I can't find a way to make a tmux pane restart its current process; tmux doesn't seem to know enough about the terminals it's displaying for a more resilient answer.